# How to use a dynamic value with ngClass

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to apply a class name that's the same as a scope variable.

For example:

`<div ng-class="{item.name : item.name}">`

So that the value of `item.name` is added to the class.  This doesn't seem to do anything though.  Any suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is actually being done within a select, using ng-options.  For example:

`<select ng-options="c.code as c.name for c in countries"></select>`

Now, I want to apply a class name that has the value of `c.code`

I found the following directive, which seems to work, but not with interpolation of the value:

```
angular.module('directives.app').directive('optionsClass', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  'use strict';

  return {
    require: 'select',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngSelect) {
      // get the source for the items array that populates the select.
      var optionsSourceStr = attrs.ngOptions.split(' ').pop(),
      // use $parse to get a function from the options-class attribute
      // that you can use to evaluate later.
          getOptionsClass = $parse(attrs.optionsClass);

      scope.$watch(optionsSourceStr, function(items) {
        // when the options source changes loop through its items.
        angular.forEach(items, function(item, index) {
          // evaluate against the item to get a mapping object for
          // for your classes.
          var classes = getOptionsClass(item),
          // also get the option you're going to need. This can be found
          // by looking for the option with the appropriate index in the
          // value attribute.
              option = elem.find('option[value=' + index + ']');

          // now loop through the key/value pairs in the mapping object
          // and apply the classes that evaluated to be truthy.
          angular.forEach(classes, function(add, className) {
            if(add) {
              angular.element(option).addClass(className);
            }
          });
        });
      });
    }
  };

}]);
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I'm on angular 1.5.5 and none of these solutions worked for me.

It is possible to use the array and map syntax at once though it's only shown in [the last example here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

```
<div ng-class="[item.name, {'other-name' : item.condition}]">
```

Comment: I was looking for this. One with condition and one with variable name. Thanks I know now that array syntax. :-)

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. Really hard to find the right search terms for this! Thank you.

Comment: on angular 1.6.4 it doesn't seems to update the classname when the condition changes

Answer (score 74):

Better later than never.

```
<div ng-class="{'{{item.name}}' : item.condition}">
```

yes. `'` and `{{` for classname.

Comment: That's the proper one for when your class names are scope-defined variables.

Comment: This works for 1 condition, but if you try to add `,` and another condition with value it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Also this doesn't update the classname when the condition changes

Comment: @CristianMuscalu - This worked with multiple conditions when I added this logic at the end. Eg: "{'red':item.name='abc','{{item.name}}' : item.condition}"

Answer (score 12):

Simply using the variable should be sufficient:

```
<div ng-class="item.name" />
```

This is also documented in the [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Comment: Hm, ok my question was not clear enough.  I'm actually doing this with `ng-options` in a select box and want to use the value of the select and apply it to the option.

Comment: @dave it is still the same, just `c.code` instead of `item.name`

Comment: Doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: For the original question this would be the right answer :)

Answer (score 7):

I think you missed the concept.

A conditional css class looks like this:

```
<div ng-class="{'<css_class_name>': <bool_condition>}">
```

And I dont think you want:

```
<div ng-class="{'true': true}">
```

You probally want to use:

`<div ng-class="item.name"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Angularjs Apply class with condition:

```
<div ng-class="{true:'class1',false:'class2'}[condition]" >
```

Comment: This condition return true or false value,  <div ng-class="{true:'class1',false:'class2'}[statusId==1 ]" >

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful in some cases:

HTML:

```
<div ng-class="getCssClass()"></div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getCssClass = function () {
    return { item.name: item.name };
};
```

Comment: that's the best solution if you need more logic for css classes