# Using variable in conditional implementation of ngClass

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I have developed an Angular 2 application in which I am trying to apply a CSS class using `ngClass`. I have stored the class name in a variable `className` and tried below code to apply:

1. First way

   ```
   [ngClass]={'{{className}}': expression}
   ```
2. Second way

   ```
   [ngClass]= {className: expression}
   ```

But neither of them worked.

Comment: What is `expression`? It needs to return `true`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a dynamic value with ngClass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563001/how-to-use-a-dynamic-value-with-ngclass)

Comment: Oh no that's Angular 1, sorry; the Angular 2 version of the question is http://stackoverflow.com/q/37090877/3001761

Comment: @K.Daniek I am trying to create a custom element which accepts classname using '@Input'.

Comment: @JayakrishnanGounder , dude , you should accept one of the below otherwise people just copy paste our answer and answer again :D:D:D:D:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**update**

```
[ngClass]="expression ? cssClass : null"
```

or just

```
[ngClass]="cssClass"
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/TK8HGhqol4fWbtTRlVC4?p=preview)

**original** (works only in Dart)

```ts
[ngClass]= {className: expression}
```

will work fine when `expression` returns `true`

Comment: I think className should  be variable here , that's the question

Comment: I just checked. That only works in Dart, but not in JS.

Comment: Why would it work anyway ? what if I the className is padding or something ? This should never work

Comment: I don't understand your comment. They implemented it just like object literals work in TS and Dart. Actually in Dart it's not an object literal but a `Map`. TS can only have string as property name, but Dart can have any value as map key.

Comment: [ngClass]="expression ? cssClass : null"  worked for me!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the condition in your template, you should bind it to a variable or function and return an Object of your class in your controller.

Template

```
<!-- From a getter -->
[ngClass]="myClass"

<!-- From a function -->
[ngClass]="myClass(someCondition)"
```

Controller

```
// As a getter
get myClass(): any {

    return {
        someClass: someTruthyCondition
    }
}

// From a function
myClass(someCondition): any {

    return {
         someClass: someCondition === true
    }
}
```

Comment: function calls in template is bad practice

Answer (score 0):

You should use interpolation like this :

```
<div  class="{{expression?className:null}}" ></div>
```

This is a example :

```
<div  class="{{something===anotherThing?className:null}}" ></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work on Safari mobile AFAIK and therefore binding to `class` is discouraged.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , oh , that's a shame , do you know why ?

Comment: Browser bug. . . .. . .

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer , is there any issue raised or is this documented somewhere ? how do we know this ?

Comment: AFAIK it was discussed in a GitHub issue months ago, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Just tested in Safari mobile , it's working fine for me , I have Iphone6 ios.10

Comment: Thanks for checking. Perhaps it was fixed in the browser since then or the polyfill got improved.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code it works for me.

**Assign class in variable:**

```
class1: string = "class1";
class2: string = "class2";
```

**Style:**

```
<style>
.class2 {
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    width:100px;            
}
 .class1 {
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
    width:100px;
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div [ngClass]="1==1?class1:class2">
    Test Class
</div>
```

**Development Tool Code:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]