# ng-class set class name from dynamic value and add extra conditions

Tags: angularjs

I was looking for the syntax to add classname from a value.
Just before giving up ,i found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24563001/how-to-use-a-dynamic-value-with-ngclass) an answer that works.
Now the problem is you can't add `,` like you would normally and add more conditions.

What would be the correct **syntax for Ex2 to work?**

**Ex1: This works:**

```
ng-class="{'{{obj.status}}' : obj.status}"
```

**Ex2: This doesn't work:** (also no error in the console)

```
ng-class="{'{{obj.status}}': obj.status, 'isEmployee': status == 'isEmployee'}"
```

---

**Update:**

I didn't change anything relevant any now it works >< Give me some time to figure out what the hell is going on ...

I know what i did to make it work. I was trying to change something else and i added this to the controller that made it work, because it's basically the same data :

```
$scope.status= obj.status
```

This would be the solution in my case.

**Copy/Pasted the exact code** for the button, since you all say it should work. Can you spot something wrong with it?

```
<md-button ng-class="{'{{editedObject.interviewStatus}}' : editedObject.interviewStatus, 'isEmployee': interviewStatus == 'isEmployee'}" aria-label="OpenStatusMenu" ng-click="$mdMenu.open($event)">
```

Comment: That's just a typo here. I will fix it.

Comment: are you sure $scope.status value is isEmployee?

Answer (score 1):

please check your obj and status value it's look like this?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope,$http,$q) {
  $scope.obj = {
    "status":"abc"
  }
  $scope.status = "isEmployee";
});
```

```css
.abc{
    color: blue;
  }
  .isEmployee{
    background-color: pink;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<span ng-class="{'{{obj.status}}': obj.status, 'isEmployee': status == 'isEmployee'}">both class added</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, i was thinking maybe there is some other `['..']` syntax that i am missing. I will rewrite the whole part, maybe i have a typo or something. Thanks for the Demo!

Answer (score 0):

A comma should work. You might have forgotten the `"` at the end?

Comment: I didn't change anything relevant any now it works >< Give me some time to figure it out. Thanks guys anyway.